# Why are labels visible through a basemap?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, basemap, transparency-opacity

I'm working with a custom basemap I created as a vector-tile and published it to AGOL, but I noticed labels are visible through it in both AGOL and ArcGIS Pro. Can anyone explain why this behavior possible? In the image, you can see that the basemap is covering my other layers, yet I can still see the labels for the building and safe zone layer.
[image]

Comment: What sort of labels are they? Graphical text, annotation feature class or feature labeling?  An annotation feature class can be moved down the drawing order but the label drawing phase comes after the feature drawing phase and graphical drawing phase. The Esri draw phases are listed https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000000s3000000 with the complete refresh starting at 0 and ending at 64 (32 really as 64 has nothing in it) labels are created in esriViewForeground which is drawn after everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are feature labeling using Maplex labeling engine. Is there any way to correct so the basemap can cover the labels? Whenever I publish this map (feature layers and custom basemap) on AGOL and selected ESRI's light gray basemap, the labels from this basemap are visible through my custom basemap.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no way to adjust the labeling of this product. It appears to be using a WMS type where the tile is generated as a JPEG on the server and sent to your local tilecache where it acts as any georeferenced raster does. If it were a WFS type the features in the extent are sent to your local and rendered there, in that case there is a possibility of modifying the layer because the work is done locally. The use of the Maplex label engine makes no difference to the existence of labels it just does a better job of placing the labels your layers make.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are not drawn in the same graphics layer as the map layer they are associated with.  Labels from all map layers are drawn last in separate graphics layers on top of map layers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way to correct this? Whenever I publish this map (basemap, feature layers) and select the light gray ESRI basemap, there is no way to cover up the labels from the ESRI basemap